# Derivative of an integral of a two-variable function

Tags: integration, derivatives

I want to calculate the derivative of an integral of a two-variable function, so

$\frac{d}{dy}\int_{0}^1f(x,y)\,dx$.

I am sorry if this is a basic question but a google search yields unusable results. I am 90% sure that the derivative can simply go under the integral, but I would like to be sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right,

$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}y}\int_0^1{\rm d}x~f(x,y) = \int_0^1{\rm d}x~\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}
$$

Comment: Please include an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Define $$F(x,y)= \int^1_0 f(x,y)dx$$ and use the chain rule on $F(x,y)$.

This is a special case of the [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form_with_variable_limits). For a function in the form:
$$
f(x) = \int_{s(x)}^{g(x)} h(x, t) dt,
$$
then the Liebniz rule states that
$$
\frac{df}{dx} = \int_{s(x)}^{g(x)} \partial_x h(x, t) dt + h(x, g(x)) \frac{dg}{dx} - h(x, s(x)) \frac{ds}{dx}.
$$

It should boil down to something quite simple after a couple of lines.